# It looks that javers doesn't handle properly comparing generic types in value objects?

Tags: java, generics, javers

What can be done to make javers treat token types as value objects and compare such objects property by property? It looks that ValueChangeAppender is used to compare such objects and it eventually delegates comparison to Objects.equals, which in case equal is not implemented leads to undesirable result.

To make things a little bit clearer I would like javers to satisfy below assertion:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
            Ob<Field> o1 = new Ob<>(new Field("A"));
            Ob<Field> o2 = new Ob<>(new Field("A"));
            Diff diff = javers.compare(o1, o2);
            assertThat(diff.hasChanges(), is(false));
        }

        public static class Ob<T> {
            private final T field;

            public Ob(T field) {
                this.field = field;
            }
        }

        public static class Field {
            private final String something;

            public Field(String something) {
                this.something = something;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas, how should I approach such a scenario? Is javers capable to satisfy above assertion?

Answer (score 0):

Token type can be anything, in runtime it's nothing more than `Object.class`, if you can suggest better strategy for comparing two instances of Object.class (better than calling Object.equals()) please share.

Comment: Thanks for reply, not sure if it is better, but it would fit my case if objects were compared property by property, through reflection. I am using JaVers to alleviate the fact that classes which I check for equality do not implement equals, that is the whole point. So the default strategy here which assumes that equals is implemented doesn't work well for me. Perhaps we could choose strategy when configuring JaVers. I chose JaVers for unit testing, but perhaps there are better libs for delivering custom equality like Unitils, with its refflective equals.